# Convert LINQ to List<T> to Python 2.7

Tags: linq, python-2.7

I'm attempting to convert the following statement to python (2.7):

```
List<int> data = Entities.MyData.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
```

In Python, I'm able to do the following (using SQLAlchemy)

```
myData = MyData().query.all() 
data = []
for m in myData:
    data.append(m.Id)
```

The thing is, is this does not seem very clean. I know python always has a better way of doing things, but with my noob-ness of Python, I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = [d.Id for d in MyDate().query.all()]
```

Those are called [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).